# Is my Apache conf on never ending loop, how can I improve?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, mod-proxy

I'm looking to improve my conf file and how can I make it more accurate and what changes are needed to the below conf file

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName appname.cloud.com
     RewriteEngine On
     
     ProxyPass /appname/  http://localhost:7000/appname/
     RedirectMatch permanent "^/$" "https://appname.cloud.com/appname/"

     RewriteRule ^/appname-mobile/(.*) http://localhost:7001/appname-mobile/$1 [P,L]
     ProxyPassReverse /appname-mobile/ http://localhost:7001/appname-mobile/

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: For which purpose are you using redirect match and rule?

Comment: When base URL is hit I want the apache to automatically direct it to /appname